# Eclipse "Open Type" window shows double

Tags: eclipse, types, classpath

When I open the "Open Type" window in Eclipse, ctrl+shift+T, I see the same type show up multiple times.  The types have exactly the same package and name. Why would it do that and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You have probably added the same library twice, e.g. in two different jars.  Look at your referenced libraries to see if you can find duplicates.

In my Eclipse (Helios) the full path of the jar file appears after the class name in the 'Open Type' menu.

Comment: Either has the same type in different jars or it is showing a history of recently opened types. For instance, I'm using 3 different environments and `Thread` is implemented in all of them. So, in my case `Thread` appears 3 times.

Comment: I think my problem stems from gwt-user and gwt-servlet jars both are on my classpath. Is there any way to filter the results so I can choose to see only a single implementation?

Comment: @Matthew see [type filters](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-dialog-open-type.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but type filters will create another problem. It will not display the type at all.  The type filter works off name or package.  Since both have the same name, it would filter them both, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

Same name class are present in more than one project or package.It ll show that much time

For example you add same jar in reference library to more than one project from different path.Then open type of eclipse show Class which you are searching, in more than one time.It simply scan all the places and showing.

You can notice this in Open type dialog itself `ClassName(-)Path`.If you point the same place then it will restrict